# How do I detect if my app is sandboxed?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

I have an application that is targeted to run in both sandboxed and non-sandboxed MacOS. If a user upgrades from MacOS 10.6 to a later OS I need the user to re-pick folders so I can bookmark them with secure bookmarks.

How do I detect that my application is on an OS that supports sandboxing?

Answer (score 25):

The only way I know of is to look for `APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID` environment variable. It is present when the app is running inside a sandbox container.

```
NSDictionary* environ = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
BOOL inSandbox = (nil != [environ objectForKey:@"APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID"]);
```

Comment: Exactly I'm looking for! I'll give it a try and revise this comment if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Note: This no longer works on macOS Sierra (beta 1, 2 & 3 so far).

Answer (score 8):

```
BOOL isSandboxed = NO;

SecStaticCodeRef staticCode = NULL;
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];

if (SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath((__bridge CFURLRef)bundleURL, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &staticCode) == errSecSuccess) {
    if (SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(staticCode, kSecCSBasicValidateOnly, NULL, NULL) == errSecSuccess) {
        SecRequirementRef sandboxRequirement;
        if (SecRequirementCreateWithString(CFSTR("entitlement[\"com.apple.security.app-sandbox\"] exists"), kSecCSDefaultFlags,
                                       &sandboxRequirement) == errSecSuccess)
        {
            OSStatus codeCheckResult = SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(staticCode, kSecCSBasicValidateOnly, sandboxRequirement, NULL);
            if (codeCheckResult == errSecSuccess) {
                isSandboxed = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    CFRelease(staticCode);
}
```

Comment: It checks is valid entitlement “com.apple.security.app-sandbox” exist for specified application bundle. "Yes" means application is sandboxed.
Detailed API information you can found here  https://developer.apple.com/reference/security

Answer (score 5):

Testing this for Swift3

```
func isSandboxed() -> Bool {
    let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    var staticCode:SecStaticCode?
    var isSandboxed:Bool = false
    let kSecCSDefaultFlags:SecCSFlags = SecCSFlags(rawValue: SecCSFlags.RawValue(0))

    if SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(bundleURL as CFURL, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &staticCode) == errSecSuccess {
        if SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(staticCode!, SecCSFlags(rawValue: kSecCSBasicValidateOnly), nil, nil) == errSecSuccess {
            let appSandbox = "entitlement[\"com.apple.security.app-sandbox\"] exists"
            var sandboxRequirement:SecRequirement?

            if SecRequirementCreateWithString(appSandbox as CFString, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &sandboxRequirement) == errSecSuccess {
                let codeCheckResult:OSStatus  = SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(staticCode!, SecCSFlags(rawValue: kSecCSBasicValidateOnly), sandboxRequirement, nil)
                if (codeCheckResult == errSecSuccess) {
                    isSandboxed = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isSandboxed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here answer of @hamstergene in Swift 4.2:

```
func isSandboxEnvironment() -> Bool {
    let environ = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    return (nil != environ["APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID"])
}
```

Comment: shorter: `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID"] != nil`

Comment: confirmed working on macOS 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

I translated a new Swift 5 version of @Oleksii's code:

```
import Security

extension Bundle {
    var isSandboxed: Bool {
        let defaultFlags: SecCSFlags = .init(rawValue: 0)
        var staticCode: SecStaticCode? = nil
        
        if SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(self.bundleURL as CFURL, defaultFlags, &staticCode) == errSecSuccess {
            if SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(staticCode!, SecCSFlags(rawValue: kSecCSBasicValidateOnly), nil, nil) == errSecSuccess {
                let requirementText = "entitlement[\"com.apple.security.app-sandbox\"] exists" as CFString
                var sandboxRequirement: SecRequirement?
                if SecRequirementCreateWithString(requirementText, defaultFlags, &sandboxRequirement) == errSecSuccess {
                    if SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors(staticCode!, defaultFlags, sandboxRequirement, nil) == errSecSuccess {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
isSandboxed = Bundle.main.isSandboxed
```